# Can't update my Symfony application dependencies using doctrine

Tags: php, composer-php, symfony-3.4

I'm trying to update my symfony dependencies using composer but i'm getting an error.

I've tried using composer.phar update but it seems not to be working.

```
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.



Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.20
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.19
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.18
    - Conclusion: remove symfony/symfony v3.4.17
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.17
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.16
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.15
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.14
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.13
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.12
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.11
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.10
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.9
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.8
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.7
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.6
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.5
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.4
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.3
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.2
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.1|install symfony/symfony v3.4.2
    - don't install symfony/templating v3.4.2|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.0
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.0|remove symfony/templating v3.4.2
    - Installation request for symfony/symfony 3.4.* -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v3.4.0, v3.4.1, v3.4.10, v3.4.11, v3.4.12, v3.4.13, v3.4.14, v3.4.15, v3.4.16, v3.4.17, v3.4.18, v3.4.19, v3.4.2, v3.4.20, v3.4.3, v3.4.4, v3.4.5, v3.4.6, v3.4.7, v3.4.8, v3.4.9].
    - Installation request for symfony/templating v3.4.2 -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v3.4.2], symfony/templating[v3.4.2].
```

Do Any one have an idea ? 
Thank you !

Comment: paste your composer.json file, and the command you're trying to ran.

Comment: @Federkun see the answer below

Comment: replace `"symfony/templating": "v3.4.2",`, try with `"symfony/templating": "^3.4",`

Comment: getting same error

Comment: Have you tried ```rm -rf ./vendor && composer install``` after  setting```"symfony/templating": "^3.4"```

Comment: Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in composer.json. You may be getting outdated dependencies. Run update to update them.
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for symfony/symfony v3.4.17 -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v3.4.17].
    - don't install symfony/templating v3.4.2|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.17
    - Installation request for symfony/templating v3.4.2 -> satisfiable by symfony/templating[v3.4.2].